# Error from IIS module after removed

Tags: iis-7.5, httpmodule

I was trying out an IIS module on my development machine and stupidly installed it in a folder with an application that gets overwritten by source control.  I've tried removing the module, but now every time I try to start my app pool it fails upon first request with an error in the event log -- "The Module DLL D:\Projects\myProject\Websites\mySite\Bin\mod_h264_streaming.dll failed to load.  The data is the error."

I deleted the module using appcmd, and it no longer appears in the list.  What else should I check to remove this?

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to resolve it in IIS manager by clicking going to the "Modules" section for the server, clicking "Configure Native Modules...", selecting the module, and clicking Remove.